# MariaDB datetime field type is returning different results since update

Tags: sql, database, mariadb

The server was recently updated to MariaDB and PHP 7 and this has caused a problem with some SQL queries in which are now returning null when before they weren't before.

This returns no results:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_applications` WHERE `date_received` < 1
```

This returns 735 results:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_applications` WHERE `date_received` = 0
```

I could update the query, but it's likely there are other undiscovered issues in another part of the system with the same problem. Is there a way to allow the first option to work as it did previously by changing a setting in the database?

date_received is a datetime type

Comment: You check a datetime column like that? You should change your queries. If the fields can be `NULL` then use `date_received is null` and `date_received is not null`

Comment: The fields cannot be null, unfortunately I inherited a horrible database. The SQL may not be the best, but it's already there and I'm worried that I'll miss updating SQL queries as the system has sooooo many aspects to it that I would need to double check. Hence why I want to know if I can change the database settings

Comment: You should mention the mariadb versions (old -> new); there where changes to datetime handling in 10.1.2 -- you have to update old datetime columns with an ALTER TABLE command, or turn the new feature off (`mysql56_temporal_format=OFF`).  See here for more information https://mariadb.com/kb/en/datetime/#internal-format

Comment: @TomRegner You're right except I don't know what the old version was, except that it was MySQL and probably not updated in 10+ years. I know it was running PHP 5 before and now 7.2

Comment: Then chances are you're bitten by this change.

Comment: Haha, it will definitely be good in the long run, just might have some teething issues. Most of the PHP had been updated so there wasn't much that was redundant. It's the database update that seems to have caused a couple of issues

Comment: Why are you comparing a "date time" value with an integer? That's a wrong query to begin with. Shouldn't that be something like `where date_received < '2020-11-05'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm not sure why it was written like that, but that's whats there

Comment: Wow, any self-respecting DBMS would flat out reject that statement with an error

Comment: Is MySQL not a DBMS?

Comment: @milky_jay . . . Focus on the "self-respecting" ;)  It also used to allow unaggregated columns in `group by` and has some other deviations from the standards.

Comment: Are there 735 rows in the table?  Please provide some examples.